# Slidesjs doesn't make slides clickable

Tags: click, slider

I have embedded the Slidesjs slider into my website. I am trying to understand how to make the slides clickable, because even if I have wrapped the img elements in an anchor element the clicking doesn't seem to work properly.

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">
        <div><a href="#"><img src="img/slider/slide1.png" alt="Slide #1"></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"><img src="img/slider/slide2.png" alt="Slide #2"></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"><img src="img/slider/slide3.png" alt="Slide #3"></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"><img src="img/slider/slide4.png" alt="Slide #4"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What should happen when you click a link?

Comment: @Purr the idea is visiting an external page on another website

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the same problem, and it was the 'bottom' argument in slidesLoaded function. I changed

```
    slidesLoaded: function() {
      $('.caption').animate({
        bottom:0
      },200);
    }
```

to

```
    slidesLoaded: function() {
      $('.caption').animate({
        bottom:-200
      },200);
    }
```

and it works.

So, I have height of 270px slides my final script is like below.

```
    animationStart: function(current){
      $('.caption').animate({
        bottom:-270
      },100);
    },
    animationComplete: function(current){
      $('.caption').animate({
        bottom:-230
      },200);
    },
    slidesLoaded: function() {
      $('.caption').animate({
        bottom:-230
      },20);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just z-index problem, Set the highest z-index in slides div and set position as relative as follow, your link will b ok now.

```
<div id="slides" style="z-index:9999999; position:relative;">
<div class="slides_container">
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/slider/slide1.png" alt="Slide #1"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/slider/slide2.png" alt="Slide #2"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/slider/slide3.png" alt="Slide #3"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/slider/slide4.png" alt="Slide #4"></a></div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example every slide points to an external web page when it's clicked: http://slidesjs.com/examples/images-with-captions/

Maybe you can try to adapt your code according to this example.

Comment: Done that, but if I try to imitate the structure the result is the slider brokes.

Comment: In what way does it break? Is there an error in the console? And maybe you could add some more information to your first post, like the javascript part, so one can try to replicate the error that you get.